# Various meanings of "mind and do" which can mean "be cautious/careful to do", "take notice/give heed and do", and "behave obediently and do"

Tags: word-usage, dialects, colloquialisms, vernacular

How would you define the meaning of "mind and do" in the following examples:

> *I will **mind and do** as I am told, Master Yoda*...
>
> ***Mind and do*** your work properly...
>
> *As long as you **mind and don't get** in the way*...
>   [AbilityMaine](http://www.abilitymaine.org/breath/win14d.html)
>
> *Please **mind and do** something for those guys*... [JustAc](http://forum.justac.net/index.php?topic=1168.0)

Comment: Where did these examples come from?

Comment: You may have misheard the idiom *Mind (that) you do your work*, where *mind* has the dictionary sense of 'be careful'.

Comment: @TimLymington Scottish dialect maybe? Still and all, I maintain that "mind" has the sense of "be careful to" in such an authoritative online dictionary as The Free Dictionary. You might just as well look it up. As for my example "I will mind and do as I am told", I'd just as soon you google that one and check out the source for yourself... ;)

Comment: From Merriam Webster: "Mind" can mean, among other things, "to give heed to attentively in order to obey" as well as "to be careful". "Mind you finish it" is given as an example of the latter, so surely the verb "do" could be used as well. I am sure I have heard the exact construction "mind and do [something]". If I remember correctly, it was common among  South African friends of mine.

Comment: @PeterShor For that, you might just as well want to consider checking on wordreference.com and look up Post#17 of the thread initiated by yours truly: "String of idiomatic infinitive verbs without "to"". ;)

Comment: 'Mind' can also mean 'to look after' as in 'I am minding the shop', or 'She minds children for a living'. I don't know if that's of any help.

Comment: @WS2 "Tend" can also be used alongside of "shop/store" with a similar meaning. ;)

Comment: @WS2 Generally speaking, Americans tend to "tend" whereas the Brits will more commonly "keep". e.g. tend the store, bar, goals, pool, elevator, desk, station, booth, car, etc. ;)

Comment: In addition, cowpunchers generally tend cattle/stock whereas sheepherders will tend flocks. ;)

Comment: @NourishedGourmet Yes Americans tend to 'tend the store', whereas we 'mind the shop'. 'Keep the shop' is not something you do on an hour by hour, minute by minute basis. It is used in the sense of 'My grandfather used to keep the village post-office'. It is particularly used with pubs e.g. 'They keep the Kings Arms at Toltwiddle.' You can also say 'He kept goal for Wigan' but that's another story.

Comment: "Tend" can also be used in that sense, "mind" absolutely not. ;)

Comment: @Sven Yargs Thanks for your answer, Sven. However, I think it would better fit in here. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is based on a false premise: “mind and do” is being asked about as if it were the verb in these examples, but it is not. Each example actually contains two sentences which are compounded together. In the compound sentence, “and” functions as a coordinator. Redundant text is elided (taken out).

The first example contains the two sentences:

- I will mind, Master Yoda.
- I will do as I am told, Master Yoda.

The second example contains the two sentences:

- Mind.
- Do your work properly.

Once the sentence is understood as a compound, the question of the meaning of “mind and do” disappears.

Comment: @MetaEd Apparently it comes from Scottish dialect and means something like "remember" or "be sure to not forget" http://www.firstfoot.com/dictionary/m.html "Mind and don't come back without some food for the alligator." And so, the idiom "mind and do" makes a lot of sense in Scottish English. ;)